# undefined index : Name in ~\order.php on line 12

Tags: php, undefined-index

i create project for customer.
when i run the project in wamp server i can view project correctly , but when costumer running project in our wamp server face this error ,

```
undefined index : Name in ~\order.php on line 12
undefined index : Name in ~\order.php on line 13
```

and line 12 and 13 is :

```
$Name = $_REQUEST['Name'];
$PhoneNo = $_REQUEST['PhoneNo'];
```

i want know that how i can view this error in my wamp server.

withal i replace code with :

```
if(isset($_REQUEST)){
$Name = $_REQUEST['Name'];
$PhoneNo = $_REQUEST['PhoneNo'];
}
```

but costumer so face this error .
i way that i face this error with setting php.ini
withal part of my php.ini is :

```
; - error_reporting = E_NOTICE
```

thanks.

Comment: The error does not match the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try using strict error reporting to see errors on your server and then use something like the ternary operator suggested by hsz. You will see all errors output in the browser window with the following line of code at the very top of your PHP script just below the first <?php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
```

to turn error reporting off so you don't see errors use this instead.

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `isset` in following way:

```
$Name = isset($_REQUEST['Name']) ? $_REQUEST['Name'] : '';
```

Comment: thanks , have you way to show this error in my computer , because this syntax is true in my wamp server , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by using hsz's method on another answer.

In the future PHP6 it would be

```
 $_REQUEST['Name'] = ifsetor($_REQUEST['Name'], "");
```

BTW do not use REQUEST array. It merges all $_COOKIE, $_GET, $_POST arrays into one. So your data can be overridden.  Besides you never know is this $_REQUEST['NAME'] is coming from GET request or POST request or from COOKIE.